# find longest noncontiguous nondecreasing subsequence in array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to prove why finding the longest non contiguous non decreasing sub sequence of an array of size n, in O(n).
By "find" I mean know its length, and a list of the relevant indices.

[Here is a solution](https://yao.page/posts/longest-noncontiguous-nondecreasing-subsequence-python/) in `NlogN`.

[Here is the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

I want to convince myself that it can't be done any faster.

---

Here is partial proof:

Assume this were possible faster than `O(nlogn)`, for simplicity, `O(n)` but this holds for anything better than `O(nlogn)`

We can merge two sorted arrays into a single sorted array composed of all elements of both in `O(n1 + n2)`.

Given an array `A`, we could then find its longest longest non contiguous non decreasing sub sequence in `O(n)`.
If this sequence is smaller then `n/2`, then for `reversed(A)` it is larger or equal to `n/2` [**I need proof for that**]

This way, we can split the array into sorted chunks, each time in `O(n)`, and being left with a remainder of size `k` that can also be split and sorted in `O(k) + O(remainer)` until we are left with one element which is `O(1)`.

Thus, sorting the array would take `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a solution in `O(n+klogk)`, where k is the number of elements which are in an unsorted position.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764861/how-to-sort-an-array-with-n-elements-in-which-k-elements-are-out-of-place-in-on)

Armed with the above algorithm, we can find which of the k elements are out of their position by sorting using the above algorithm `O(n+klogk)` and traversing the unsorted and the sorted arrays together, finding the indices of the k (or less) differences (single pass, `O(n)`).

The rest of the indices would define a sorted array which is also a non consecutive subsequence of the input array, which is of the maximal length, because by definition, those indices are sorted, and the other `k` aren't.

In general, this is `O(n log n), but in case there is a need to search for a longest non consecutive subsequence, it would make sense to optimize like this, because the problem will probably be such that` n << k`.